# Average with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Trying to calculate average number of books borrowed per member. 
member(**memb no**, name, age)
book(**isbn**, title, authors, publisher)
borrowed(*memb no, isbn*, date)
Bold - Primary Key
Italic - Foreign Key
Can anyone here help me out? Thanks in Advance

Comment: sample data and expected result would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of distinct books borrowed by each member, you could do

```
select membno, count(*) as totalborrowed
from borrowed
group by membno
```

To get the total members, you could do

```
select count(distinct membno) as totalmembers
from borrowed
```

To get the average books borrowed, you should combine the results. Multiply with `1.0` to get a result in decimal.

```
select 1.0 * sum(totalborrowed)/count (distinct b.membno) as avg_per_member
from
(select membno, count(*) as totalborrowed
from borrowed
group by membno) t join borrowed b on t.membno = b.membno
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select AVG(MemberBookCount)
from (
    select count(*) * 1.0 as MemberBookCount
    from MemberBook
    group by Member
) a
```

Comment: I like you column and table names more than the OPs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT (*)  / CAST((SELECT COUNT (*) FROM member) AS FLOAT)
FROM borrowed
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is a ratio of two values:

```
select count(*) * 1.0 / count(distinct membo)
from borrowed;
```